# How to bind and unbind blur event on a text field

Tags: jquery

I have got a text Field which has got a blur event which will be useful for checking with  existing data present in database

When it in edit mode i dont want to make a DB CALL to check with database  so will be disabling this blur event .

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/50/

When  clciked on Edit button , how to disable this blur event ??

I was trying it this way

```
var value = 'Home';
fillField();

function fillField() {
   $("#label").val(value);
}



$(document).on('click', '#editbtn', function (event) {
   $("#label").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#label").val(value);
    $('#label').unbind("blur");
});



$(document).on('blur', '#label', function (event) {
alert('onblur fired');
});
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the blur event is not attached to the specific label that you are trying to unbind. It's attached to the document then it searches for the #label selector in the event's targets.

The problem with using `$(document).off('blur', '#label')` is that since you're using on to bind the elements, which might be dynamically added, it will turn all of the events matching the criteria off not just for a specific label.

You could always make a data- property or a global variable to distinguish between elements being edited and not worry about rebinding blur.

This assumes you had a reason for binding it to the document and not the actual label. Which would be better for just a single text field and button.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it...

```
$(document).on('click', '#editbtn', function (event) {
   $("#label").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#label").val(value);
    $(document).off('blur', '#label');
});
```

Using .off instead of .unbind, and turning off the original event

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = 'Home';
fillField();

function fillField() {
   $("#label").val(value);
}



$(document).on('click', '#editbtn', function (event) {
   $("#label").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#label").val(value);
    $('#label').unbind("blur");
});



$('#label').on('blur', function (event) {
alert('onblur fired');
});
```